# c++ regex won't match spaces

Tags: c++, regex

Please help............................................
My regex won't work on spaces:

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

#include<sstream>
#include<fstream>
#include<list>
#include<numeric>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>

#include<regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    regex date3{R"([A-Z][a-z]{2,}\s\d{1,})"};
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    smatch matches;
    if(regex_match(s,matches,date3)){
        cout<<matches[0];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried

```
regex date3{R"([A-Z][a-z]{2,} \d{1,})"};
```

For example, I input `May 3` and it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin>>s` splits the input on white space and discards those white spaces.
Instead you may want to use for instance `getline(cin, s)`.